# pipe to filter data from JSON getting error-Template parse

Tags: angular

I think I missed few things about pipe..so my solution not working
I have a JSON file which contain data of products. the products can be sort by "ProductTags" - JSON with the tag they can be filter by. also, I have JSON Which contain details about the filter:

```
"PriceFilter": [
{
    "TagId": 20,
    "Type": "Budget",
    "Value": 5,
    "Values": null,
    "DisplayText": "$5",
    "Order": null
},
{
    "TagId": 21,
    "Type": "Budget",
    "Value": 10,
    "Values": null,
    "DisplayText": "$10",
    "Order": null
}]
```

product:

```
"Products": [
{
    "ProductId": 206419,
    "ProductTitle": "Mom is Fabulous Fruit Box - Good",
    "ProductTags": [ 20, 2, 3, 4 ]
}]
```

I need to order the products using the tags in this way: [price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqk7f.png)

store. html

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let P of PriceFilter | filter : term | orderBy: 'Price'">
        <td>{{PriceFilter.DisplayText}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

store component:

```
stores=[];
products=[];

PriceFilter = [];
GenderFilter =[];
filtered=[];
constructor(private _storeService:StoreService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getProducts()
       .subscribe(data =>{
           this.products = data.Stores.Products;
           this.stores=data.Stores;
           this.PriceFilter = data.PriceFilter;
           this.GenderFilter = data.GenderFilter;
           console.log(data.PriceFilter)
           console.log(data.GenderFilter)
           console.log(data.Stores)
       });     
}
```

filter pipe:

```
transform(items: any[], term): any {
    console.log('term', term);

    return term 
        ? items.filter(item => item.ProductTags.indexOf(term) !== -1)
        : items;
}
```

orderBy pipe:

```
export class OrderbyPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: any[], orderBy: string): any {
    console.log('orderdBy', orderBy);

    return items.sort((a, b) => {return b[orderBy] - a[orderBy]});
}
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @user184994 what to do to fix the error

Comment: Can you please let us know the full error, and also which line is causing the error? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see your filter pipe is correct. but is your orderBy pipe correct?

in your orderBy pipe try:

```
items.sort((a, b) => a[orderBy].toLowerCase() !== b[orderBy].toLowerCase() ? a[orderBy].toLowerCase() < b[orderBy].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1 : 0);
```

and pass your pipe in your html as,

```
<tr *ngFor="let P of PriceFilter | filter : term | orderBy: ['Price']">
    <td>{{PriceFilter.DisplayText}}</td>
</tr>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this will work: you wouldn't want to use an array as the key to an object

Comment: doesn't ngfor handle only Array? but as you mentioned, we cannot find where is fault at without knowing the error. At a glance, i thought fixing order by might solve the issue.

Comment: @reddevilzee    ERROR TypeError: a[orderBy] is not a function
    at order-by.pipe.ts:9
    at Array.sort (:4200/native)
    at OrderByPipe.push../src/app/order-by.pipe.ts.Orde

Comment: I changef the order by pipe, now its with no error but nothing appears. I guess its here the problem:<tr *ngFor="let P of PriceFilter | filter : term | orderBy: ['Price']">
    <td>{{PriceFilter.DisplayText}}</td>
</tr>@reddevilzee

Comment: Use `<input type="text" #term="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />`

Answer (score 0):

> #### Issue :
>
> As per your pipe `OrderbyPipe` definition `params` is `string` however you are passing `array` from the html.

```
<tr *ngFor="let P of PriceFilter | filter : term | orderBy: ['Price']">
    <td>{{PriceFilter.DisplayText}}</td>
</tr>
```

> #### Fix :

```
<tr *ngFor="let P of PriceFilter | filter : term | orderBy: 'Price'">
    <td>{{PriceFilter.DisplayText}}</td>
</tr>
```

> #### Note

term is dynamic so make sure it is bind with any kind of search element.

Ex :

```
<input type="text" #term="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
```

Comment: You should pass the `term`. Updated answer with example.

Comment: Thanks! but getting error of: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("<h2>store</h2>
<input type="text" [ERROR ->]#term="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="term"/> I think maybe some changes in the HTML needed